# Show post in slider

Tags: php, jquery, css, javascript, html

I am working on wordpress project .I want to show the post details in such away that the first four post thumbnail  would  show on the top and show the content of first post below, after clicking on next arrow it hover the next thumbnail and show the detail of next post below.
I am using carousel slider for this purpose
below is my code

```
 <script>   
                      $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
  interval: 4000
})
$('.carousel .item').each(function(){
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {

    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

  for (var i=0;i<2;i++) {
    next=next.next();
    if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }

    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
  });
  });
    </script>
```

My HTML Design is

```
<div class="col-md-12 text-center"><h3>Bootstrap 3 Multiple Slide Carousel</h3></div>
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
  <?php

  $args = array('post_type' => 'testimonial', 'posts_per_page'  => $posts_per_page,
          'tax_query' => array(array('taxonomy' => 'testimonial_category', 'field' => 'name', 'terms' => $category,)));
query_posts( $args );
 $i = 0;
//var_dump($args );
          while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
      $item_class = ($i == 0) ? 'item active' : 'item'; //Set class active for image which is showing
     ?>
    <div class="<?php echo $item_class; ?>">
      <div class="col-md-3 onclick_image testimonial-image<?php echo $i; ?>"" num ="<?php echo $i; ?>" postid="<?php echo get_the_id(); ?>">
        <?php 
                the_post_thumbnail();
           the_title(); 
           the_content();   
     $i++; ?>
      </div>
    </div>
     <?php 
   endwhile;

// Reset Query
wp_reset_query(); 
 ?>

  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
</div>
</div>
```

I want such a result
[image]

Comment: Never ever use `query_posts`, it breaks a lot of stuff

Comment: @Pieter Goosen thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this to show images on slider .Try this

```
<div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="carousel carousel-showmanymoveone slide" id="carousel123">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"> <img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'img/download-1.jpg'; ?>"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"> <img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'img/download-1.jpg'; ?>"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"> <img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'img/download-1.jpg'; ?>"></div>
          </div>          
          <div class="item">
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"> <img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'img/download-1.jpg'; ?>"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"> <img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'img/download-1.jpg'; ?>"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"> <img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'img/download-1.jpg'; ?>"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"> <img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'img/download-1.jpg'; ?>"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"> <img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'img/download-1.jpg'; ?>"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel123" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel123" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

script

```
(function(){
  $('.carousel-showmanymoveone .item').each(function(){
    var itemToClone = $(this);

    for (var i=1;i<4;i++) {
      itemToClone = itemToClone.next();

      // wrap around if at end of item collection
      if (!itemToClone.length) {
        itemToClone = $(this).siblings(':first');
      }

      // grab item, clone, add marker class, add to collection
      itemToClone.children(':first-child').clone()
        .addClass("cloneditem-"+(i))
        .appendTo($(this));
    }
  });
}());
```

css

```
.carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-control {
  width: 4%;
  background-image: none;
}
.carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-control.left {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-control.right {
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.carousel-showmanymoveone .cloneditem-1,
.carousel-showmanymoveone .cloneditem-2,
.carousel-showmanymoveone .cloneditem-3 {
  display: none;
}
@media all and (min-width: 768px) {
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .active.left,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .prev {
    left: -50%;
  }
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .active.right,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .next {
    left: 50%;
  }
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .left,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .prev.right,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .active {
    left: 0;
  }
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner .cloneditem-1 {
    display: block;
  }
}
@media all and (min-width: 768px) and (transform-3d), all and (min-width: 768px) and (-webkit-transform-3d) {
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .item.active.right,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .item.next {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(50%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(50%, 0, 0);
    left: 0;
  }
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .item.active.left,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .item.prev {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
    left: 0;
  }
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .item.left,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .item.prev.right,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .item.active {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    left: 0;
  }
}
@media all and (min-width: 992px) {
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .active.left,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .prev {
    left: -25%;
  }
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .active.right,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .next {
    left: 25%;
  }
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .left,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .prev.right,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner > .active {
    left: 0;
  }
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner .cloneditem-2,
  .carousel-showmanymoveone .carousel-inner .cloneditem-3 {
    display: block;
  }
}
```